# Remove a object from a file in java

Tags: java

Sample code:

```
else if (ninput == 4) {
                    System.out.println("Select a method\n");
                    System.out.println("1) Remove recording by index\n");
                    System.out.println("2) Remove recording by name\n");

                    sinput = scan.next();
                    ninput = Integer.parseInt(sinput);

                    if (ninput == 1) {
                        System.out.println("INDEX ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.numberOfRecordings; i ++) {
                            System.out.println((i+1)+ ") "+ Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.recordingList.get(i) +"\n");
                        }   
                        System.out.println("Enter the index of the recording to remove: ");
                        sinput = scan.next();
                        ninput = Integer.parseInt(sinput);
                        Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.recordingList.remove(ninput - 1);
                        Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.numberOfRecordings--;

                        System.out.println(Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.toString());
                    }
                    if (ninput == 2) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.numberOfRecordings; i ++) {
                            System.out.println((i+1)+ ") "+ Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.recordingList.get(i) +"\n");
                        }   
                        System.out.println("Enter the name of the recording to remove: ");
                        sinput = scan.next();



                    }

                    }
```

Code that needs fixing:

```
if (ninput == 2) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.numberOfRecordings; i ++) {
                            System.out.println((i+1)+ ") "+ Users.get(loginID).User_Playlist.recordingList.get(i) +"\n");
                        }   
                        System.out.println("Enter the name of the recording to remove: ");
                        sinput = scan.next();



                    }
```

Problem: The first method removes a song out of a playlist based on the index of the song in the playlist.
The second method that is incomplete would remove a song out of a playlist file based on the name of the song.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I could approach removing a singular item out of a file based on the name of the object?

Comment: You take the name, loop over all songs and compare the taken name with each song's name. As soon as you find the one, take it out (you have its index - it's the loop counter).

Comment: easy approach to begin with, possibly not the most performant one depending on how your User_Playlist works internally: walk through the entire list, comare the name to the one you are looking for. when you find it, save the current index and stop the loop. then use the same code you already have to remove the index you saved.

Answer (score 0):

You take the name, loop over all songs and compare the taken name with each song's name. As soon as you find the one, take it out (you have its index - it's the loop counter) and break out of the loop. This is the most basic way of doing it.